# Hide-show like dislike jquery script for each block

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I have really many similar blocks with like and dislike divs:

```
<div class="cal_days com_each_photo">
<img class="littleimage" src="img/calendar/calendar_2.jpg" alt="day">
<div class="com_blur">
     <div class="com_link_like" style="cursor:pointer">like!</div>
     <div class="com_link_dislike" style="cursor:pointer;display:none">dislike</div>
    </div>
```

```
 <div class="cal_days com_each_photo">
<img class="littleimage" src="img/calendar/calendar_2.jpg" alt="day">
<div class="com_blur">
     <div class="com_link_like" style="cursor:pointer">like!</div>
     <div class="com_link_dislike" style="cursor:pointer;display:none">dislike</div>
    </div>
```

...
I made jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".com_link_like").click(function () {
       $(this).hide();
       $('.com_link_dislike').show();
       $('.com_link_dislike').click(function () {
          $(this).hide();
          $('.com_link_like').show();
       })
    })
});
```

Problem: It works, but when I push "like" all my divs changed class ".com_link_dislike" to ".com_link_dislike" but I need to change it only in exact block. How it can be fixed?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want this function work only in one block, not in other similar blocks.

Comment: Can you share any demo on jsfiddle if possible...?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change the associated like/dislike, traverse the tree.

```
$(this).parent().find('.com_link_like').show();
```

will go to the parent dom, find the proper div, and show it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to get, but I think this may help:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".com_link_like").click(function () {
       $(this).hide();
       $(this).next().show();
    });
    $('.com_link_dislike').click(function () {
       $(this).hide();
       $(this).prev().show();
    });
});
```

Comment: The disadvantage of this solution (just as with @Arun P Johny, which is basicly same answer but with a bit less code) is that you can't rearrange the divs. If you decide to put the buttons in different order, you'll have to change the script too, bear that in mind ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to narrow your selector to the current elements sibling, in this case you can use .next() and .prev()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".com_link_like").click(function () {
        $(this).hide().next().show();
    })
    $('.com_link_dislike').click(function () {
        $(this).hide().prev().show();;
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tGBf4/)